# How can I investigate cases where php.exe crashes on startup in an Azure App Service with no stdout/stderr output?

Tags: php, azure

I'm trying to install ImageMagick on an Azure App Service instance running WordPress. The Azure App Service is running PHP 7.3.3 x64 otherwise fine.

1. I went to this web-page to get the right zips to download: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html
2. `phpinfo()` says I'm running PHP 7.3.3 `x64` `MSVC15` non-thread-safe, so I downloaded:

   - `php_imagick-3.4.3-7.3-nts-vc15-x64.zip`
   - `ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-vc15-x64.zip`
3. I extracted the two zip files into their own respective subdirectories in `D:\home\site\ext` directory.
4. I created an empty file at `D:\home\site\ext\extensions.ini`.
5. In the Azure App Service configuration area, I added the environment variable `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=D:\home\site\ext\`.
6. In `extensions.ini` I put this single line: `extension=D:\home\site\ext\php_imagick-3.4.3-7.3-nts-vc15-x64\php_imagick.dll`.
7. Then I restarted the Azure App Service. Since then PHP crashes immediately on startup.
8. To investigate I opened Kudu and ran the PHP command-line interface from the `wwwroot` directory:

   ```
   cd D:\home\site\wwwroot\
   php -f phpinfo.php
   ```

   - This causes PHP to crash immediately. It writes nothing to standard-output nor `stderr` (so running `php -f phpinfo.php > out.txt 2> err.txt` gives me zero-byte files `out.txt` and `err.txt`).
   - My global `php.ini` already has `display_errors = On` and `display_startup_errors = On`.
9. Nothing is logged anywhere in Azure other than that the FastCGI Extension exited unexpectedly.
10. After commenting out the `#extension=D:\home\site\ext...` line PHP works fine.

I'm assuming this might be an issue with a missing system dependency (such as VisualC++ Redistributables) but Azure claims all current VisualC++ Redistributables are pre-installed (and we can't install our own anyway).

Is there any way to investigate a process-crash-on-startup?

I know one option is WinDbg, but I don't know how to get a crash dump in an Azure App Service.

Comment: Also this is an old post, today I would check the diagnosis info: Overview-> Tab Diagnose and solve problems -> Tab Diagnostic Tools -> Button "Application Event Logs". Did you manage to get it running? I am also struggling with that install. Thanks for a hint.

Comment: @spikey I never got this working :( Instead all image processing is done locally prior to uploading to WordPress.